flutter provider widget not updated even after calling notifyListeners()
i'm trying to get some data from firestore database and here's the NurseryProfileViewModel that I have created for getting the data
class NurseryProfileViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
  late Nursery nursery;
  bool isLoadingData = false;

  late final FirestoreRepository _firestoreRepository;
  late final AuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;

  NurseryProfileViewModel() {
    _firestoreRepository = DependencyInjection().locator.get();
    _authenticationManager = DependencyInjection().locator.get();
    getNursery();
  }

  Future<void> getNursery() async {
    isLoadingData = true;
    notifyListeners();

    try {
      nursery = await _firestoreRepository.getNursery();
      debugPrint('getNursery: ${nursery.activitiesInEnglish}'); // in this statement it shows that nursery object has been updated
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      debugPrint('Error getting nursery data: $error');
      // Handle error appropriately
    } finally {
      isLoadingData = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}

as you can see I call getNursery() in the constructor of the NurseryProfileViewModel to get the data every time the screen launches.
and here's how I update my UI
Widget _buildActivitiesWidget() => Card.outlined(
child: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      const Text('Activities'),
      const Divider(),
      Consumer<NurseryProfileViewModel>(
        builder: (context, provider, child) {
          if (provider.isLoadingData) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          final activities = provider.nursery.activitiesInEnglish;
          if (activities == null || activities.isEmpty) {
            return const Center(child: Text('No activities available'));
          }

          debugPrint('_buildActivitiesWidget: ${provider.nursery.activitiesInEnglish}'); //In this statement it always show the old data
          return GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            ),
            itemCount: activities.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    activities[index],
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
),

);
Edit
Finally here's how I created all the notifiers
 runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => LogIn()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AllNurseriesViewModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MainVieModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SettingsViewModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => NurseryProfileViewModel())
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
 );

Now what is happening is that when it comes to a specific screen to show some data and then sign out and in again (navigate to the login screen and after successfully login by default navigate back to the old screen) with another user it shows the old user data which should not be shown.
In other words, new data should be shown, and the new data that is supposed to be shown is already available at debugPrint('getNursery: ${nursery.activitiesInEnglish}'); statement in the NurseryProfileViewModel as commented in the code.
but in the widget screen debugPrint('_buildActivitiesWidget: ${provider.nursery.activitiesInEnglish}'); keeps the old value as commented in the body of _buildActivitiesWidget() method
I have tried both StatefullWidget and StatelessWidget but nothing solves the problem
Thank you for your help in advance

Show how you create NurseryProfileViewModel?

This is because you have initiated your provider in the main method. Main method Always run one time when you launch the app and it loads data via constructor only.
There are two ways to load new data.

Call get getNursery()  method after success of sign-in.
Instead of initialization of ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => NurseryProfileViewModel()) in the main method initialize this method on the Login screen. So whenever you load login new-instance will created which will have new values.


i have implemented your solution by adding a button and called getNursery() on button click but that also didn't work

Can you please put the multiprovider inside the my_app build method. And try it again.

Instead of runApp lets use it inside MyApp class build method. So the inherited widgets can work properly.
